# outerHeight() and inner pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've an issue at the first load of a page with outerHeight.

The value returned by outerHeight() is a multiple of 27.

jQuery

```
$('.entries').each(function(r) {    
$(this).attr("value", $(this).outerHeight()+15);
})
```

HTML :

```
<div class="entries">
    <div class="container_entrie">
    <span class="meta"><span class="title">Daily Inspiration #128</span> 
   <span class="date">- april 10th 2009 </span></span>      
    <img src="images/content/four.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.entries {  
position:absolute;  
overflow:hidden;
cursor:pointer;
width:200px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
padding:6px;
background-color:#171717;   
}

.meta{ 
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; float:left; width:190px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:5px; padding-right:5px;  font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; line-height:14px;
background-color:#000; 
/* for IE */
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
/* CSS3 standard */
opacity:0.7;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}           
.meta span.title{color:#FFF; }
.meta span.date{color:#999999; font-weight:normal;}
.container_entrie{position:relative; width:200px; float:left; overflow:hidden; }
```

And one all is loaded, after a refresh everithing is fine.

So I'm wondering if it's not an issue about the images in container_entrie ?

Thanks for the help =)

Comment: where do you load your style ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what your issue is. It may be that I don't understand because I'm not familiar with jQuery, but I'm not sure what your problem is. Is it a problem that outerHeight() returns a multiple of 27?

Comment: @MahdeTo I'm loading the style before the js in the head.

@A. Levy the problem is that outerHeight() should return the full height of entries (including margin and padding) but when I load the page the first time, it's return a multiple of 27.

After a refresh it's return the right height.

Comment: This is a very weird issue. I tried your sample and the problem only happens in IE, not FF. On every refresh of the page, the outerHeight goes up and down randomly.

Comment: thanks for trying ichiban, 

but I've got the issue on FF 3.0.1 too, but only at the first load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your javascript being called from? Unless you set a height on your image, you'll have issues if you're putting it in `$(...)` (the shorthand for $(document).ready). Try putting it in `$(window).load(...`) and see if that helps. Load fires after **all** content is downloaded, Ready is a pseudo event that fires when the dom is ready to be messed with.

Comment: Thanks Dan but It dosen't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: but it's working when I add width/height on pictures. =)

Thanks